# Required code to sync microsoft exchange server to iphone calender

Tags: iphone

I need your help on this topic "microsoft exchange server"

apple iPhone support to integrate many server calendar with iPhone default calendar.

In my application i have to integrate iphone default calendar and microsoft exchange server

I can't find any api document related this microsoft exchange server to integrate with my app.

please tell me how to integrate it in iPhone.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not supply any API for `Microsoft Exchange`. The calendar app does support `Exchange`, but there is no API which will allow you to use the `Exchange` support.

All you can do is integrate the calendar with [`EventKit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/FetchingEvents.html).